# C allocate a string without knowing the numbers of characters

Tags: c, string, malloc

I need to get a string without asking for a length,
I create a buffer of 100 char and when is full I do a realloc to add a space for a char at the end of the string

this is my code...could you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    char *content = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    char c;
    content[0]='\0';

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (strlen(content) < 10){
            strcat(content, &c);
            content[strlen(content)+1] = '\0';
        }
       else {
            content=realloc(content,sizeof(char)*(strlen(content))+2);
            strcat(content, &c);
            content[strlen(content)+1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf("%s",content);       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Have you tried this code? Maybe it's correct already?

Comment: Once you get over 10 characters, you will make a `realloc` for each character read...

Comment: Why dont you use scanf or gets.

Comment: are you getting the chars from a file or what? usually you should be able to know the length, if not use a stream that when closes can be saved as a string

Comment: @Lindydancer why is this wrong?...maybe is not ok for performance but isn't my goal

Comment: @Matteo: I saw it as an indication that you had not thought the problem through. Even if it works, one typically extend the allocation with a chunk of data, or even increase the size exponentially (like 100, 200, 400, 800, 1600 etc.)

Comment: Is there some overall size limit, is 64K always big enough?  If so, always allocate 64K and realloc it once after shoving the null on the end, (this assuming you have 2GB of virtual memory - if you are on a uC with 8K of RAM, just ignore me).

Comment: @MartinJames it is strategies like these that gave us software which starts out with a malloc of 1GB.

Comment: @mvds - if the OP was asking for a buffer pooling strategy for an IOCP server, I would have suggested a different design :)   Over-allocating the buffer once and resizing it once is likely to be faster than multiple allocations, even if each subsequent resize is increased geometrically.  If the runtime/OS has to move the data to realloc it, things get even worse for multiple realloc designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues here:

1. **don't** use `strcat` like that! You should pass a pointer to a `\0` terminated string, instead of a pointer to a single char. This only works by accident.
2. Keep track of the allocated memory size in a separate variable, instead of using `strlen()`.
3. Keep track of the position in the string using another separate variable, not by calling `strlen()` constantly. Set the terminating `\0` once, after the loop is done.
4. a better reallocation strategy would be to grow memory allocation in chunks, i.e. not for every byte. You could allocate X bytes every time your allocated memory is exhausted, or you could double the number of allocated bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You should do what @cnicutar suggested:

```
content[index] = c;
```

Also, there is another problem in your code. When you concatenate "c" to "content", you are overwriting the '\0' in the end of "content". Remember that strlen will look for a '\0'.

Another problem is:

```
content[strlen(content)+1] = '\0';
```

When your strlen is 9, you'll be placing the '\0' at content[10]. You have allocated "content" with size 10, so it means that it goes from content[0] to content[9].

A simple

```
content[strlen(content)] = '\0';
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: regarding "overwriting the \0", `man strcat` says `The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the null-terminated string s2 to the end of the null-terminated string s1, then add a terminating \0`